# What is the determiner of "o suficiente" in "Nós temos tempo o suficiente." doing?

Tags: adjetivos, determinantes

"Nós temos tempo o suficiente." means "We have enough time."

What is the purpose of the determiner "o" in that sentence? "o suficiente" appears to be used just like a plain "suficiente" (or "bastante") would be, as an `adjective`.

I could imagine a structural change like "Nós temos o tempo [que é] suficiente" but putting the "o" in front of.. what seems like an adjective, is peculiar enough to warrant asking the question.

***note***: bounty now awarded for Jacinto's answer

Comment: Isso diz-se assim no Brasil? Essa frase parece-me no mínimo marginal em português de Portugal. Se a visse pensaria que era uma confusão com o construções como "não gosto o suficiente (para qualquer coisa)", "é bom o suficiente", onde "o suficiente" significa "suficientemente".

Comment: Para sua comparação ficar mais clara: "Nós temos tempo suficiente pra sermos felizes o suficiente?"

Comment: Roberto, I've added an English version.

Comment: Jacinto your very first edit was already good enough that I wanted to reward your answer. in 14 hours it will let me add a bounty and then give you rep for it. thank you again.

Comment: I'm certainy glad you liked my answer. Awarding a 50 point reward was unnecessary though. An upvote is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Português (in English below)

Embora a expressão ***tempo o suficiente*** me soe estranha, a verdade é que a [encontramos em muitos livros](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22), todos recentes, e parece-me que publicados no Brasil. Também encontrei *dinheiro o suficiente, espaço o suficiente*, etc.. O ***o*** não faz nada: em todos os exemplos que vi ***tempo o suficiente*** poderia ser substituído por ***tempo suficiente*** sem alteração de significado.

Parece-me que se trata de uma última extensão do uso de ***o suficiente***. Um dos significados de [***suficiente*** no Aulete digital é:](http://www.aulete.com.br/suficiente)

> [substantivo masculino] **4.** Aquilo que satisfaz, que basta ou é bastante: *tem o **suficiente** para viver bem por longos anos.*

Andei a ver este [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) e parece que *o suficiente* começou por ser usado como objeto direto do verbo, como no exemplo do Aulete, *ter o suficiente*. Depois passou a ser também usado com locução adverbial: *aproximar-se o suficiente*. Mais tarde ainda, passou a modificar adjetivos: *grande o suficiente*. E parece que por fim qualifica também substantivos: *tempo o suficiente*. De maneira que *o suficiente* tem atualmente quatro usos diferentes. Mostro alguns exemplos, incluindo os mais antigos que encontrei de cada tipo.

Encontrei *o suficiente* usado como objeto direto de verbos desde meados do século XIX:

> (a) Visto que estais tão desprendidos de interesse, que não hesitais em fazer-lhe sacrifício dos vossos bens, podeis ceder-lhe ***o suficiente*** para o compensar da perda. (Júlio Diniz, [*A Morgadinha dos Canaviais*](http://www.portalsaofrancisco.com.br/alfa/julio-dinis/a-morgadinha-dos-canaviais-cronicas-da-aldeia.php), 1868.)
>
> (b) O que preciso saber é se estás disposta a ir ter comigo (…) Não por enquanto, está claro. Quando eu ganhar ***o suficiente*** para vivermos, embora como pobres; mas tendo a nossa casa. (José Régio, *O Príncipe com Orelhas de Burro*, 1942.)

No último exemplo, lemos *o suficiente* como objeto direto de *ganhar*. Mas não escandalizaria se substituíssemos *o suficiente* por *suficientemente*. E mais recentemente encontra-se *o suficiente* com este significado, usado inequivocamente como locução adverbial:

> (c) Alfreda sorriu. Aproximou-se dele ***o suficiente*** para beijar-lhe o rosto. (Gastão de Holanda, *O Burro de Ouro*, 1960.)
>
> (d) Raimundo Silva senta-se num banco de pedra, (…) ao castelo conhece-o ***o suficiente*** para não ter de voltar hoje, mesmo sendo dia de inventário. (José Saramago, *História do Cerco de Lisboa*, 1989.)

Como modificador de adjetivos, o uso de *o suficiente* parece ser ainda mais recente:

> (e) O parque, grande ***o suficiente*** para conter um estádio de futebol, é ricamente arborizado e possui uma vegetação rasteira que chega à altura da canela. (Luiz Alfredo Garcia Rosa, *O silêncio da Chuva*, 1996.)

E por fim passou também a qualificar substantivos, como no poema [*O Suficiente* de Li Barbosa (2007)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=GgwtBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0ojwmLnKAhXGfRoKHeBIAHMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&f=false):

> (f) Quero apenas o suficiente… Quero paz o suficiente para viver em serenidade; Quero alegria o suficiente para sentir felicidade (…)

E para que não se pense que é só na poesia, aqui temos um dos muitos exemplos de *o suficiente* usado na prosa, [Leonardo Saraiva,  *A Fúria*, (2010):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Y804BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0ojwmLnKAhXGfRoKHeBIAHMQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&f=false)

> (g) Queria mentir, dizer que tinha tempo ***o suficiente*** para conseguir uma ambulância e salvar a sua vida se isso ainda fosse possível,

E embora seja raro, já se encontram coisas destas também em Portugal. Até já encontrei ***a suficiente***:

> O responsável acredita que a novidade do evento não criou ***motivação a suficiente*** para que tal acontecesse. [(Notícias de Setúbal, *Missão de Fé*, 6-5-2013)](http://noticiasdesetubal.pt/node/847)

Isto é perto de casa. Devia lá ir e ver se não é gralha.

### ENGLISH

The expression ***tempo o suficiente*** sounds weird to me, but the truth is that we [find it in plenty of books](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22), all of them recent and, it seems, published in Brazil. I have also found *dinheiro o suficiente, espaço o suficiente*, etc. The ***o*** doesn’t do anything: in every example I’ve checked we could substitute ***tempo suficiente*** for ***tempo o suficiente***, and it would still mean the same.

I think it is the latest extension of the use of ***o suficiente***. One of the meanings in [***suficiente*** no Aulete digital is:](http://www.aulete.com.br/suficiente)

> [substantivo masculino] **4.** Aquilo que satisfaz, que basta ou é bastante: *tem o **suficiente** para viver bem por longos anos.* ([masculine noun] **4** that that satisfies, that suffices or is enough.)

I looked around in this [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) and it looks as though *o suficiente* was first used as the direct objet of a verb, as in the example in Aulete: *ter o suficiente* (have (that that is) enough, have as much as is enough). Later it was also used as an adverbial phrase: *aproximar-se o suficiente* ([he/she] got close enough, got as close as was enough). Still later it was used to modify adjectives: *grande o suficiente* (big enough, as big as is enough) And it looks as though now it is modifying nouns as well: *tempo o suficiente* (enough time). So now *o suficiente* has four different types of use. I now show some examples, including the earliest I could find of each type.

I found *o suficiente* used as direct object of verbs from the mid 1800s onwards:

> Visto que estais tão desprendidos de interesse, que não hesitais em fazer-lhe sacrifício dos vossos bens, podeis ceder-lhe ***o suficiente*** para o compensar da perda. (Júlio Diniz, [*A Morgadinha dos Canaviais*](http://www.portalsaofrancisco.com.br/alfa/julio-dinis/a-morgadinha-dos-canaviais-cronicas-da-aldeia.php), 1868.)
>
> O que preciso saber é se estás disposta a ir ter comigo (…) Não por enquanto, está claro. Quando eu ganhar ***o suficiente*** para vivermos, embora como pobres; mas tendo a nossa casa. (José Régio, *O Príncipe com Orelhas de Burro*, 1942.)

In the last example, we read *o suficiente* as the direct objet of *ganhar* (earn what is enough). But it would not shock anyone if we substituted *suficientemente* for *o suficiente*. And more recently *o suficiente* took this meaning too, and has been unambiguously used as an adverbial phrase:

> Alfreda sorriu. Aproximou-se dele ***o suficiente*** para beijar-lhe o rosto. (Gastão de Holanda, *O Burro de Ouro*, 1960.)
>
> Raimundo Silva senta-se num banco de pedra, (…) ao castelo conhece-o ***o suficiente*** para não ter de voltar hoje, mesmo sendo dia de inventário. (José Saramago, *História do Cerco de Lisboa*,

The usage of *o suficiente* as a modifier of adjectives is even more recent:

> O parque, grande ***o suficiente*** para conter um estádio de futebol, é ricamente arborizado e possui uma vegetação rasteira que chega à altura da canela. (Luiz Alfredo Garcia Rosa, *O silêncio da Chuva*, 1996.)

And lately it has been used to modify nouns as well, as in the poem [*O Suficiente* de Li Barbosa (2007):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=GgwtBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0ojwmLnKAhXGfRoKHeBIAHMQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&f=false)

> Quero apenas o suficiente… Quero paz o suficiente para viver em serenidade; Quero alegria o suficiente para sentir felicidade (…)

Lest you think this usage is just poetic license, here is one of many similar examples found in prose, this one from [Leonardo Saraiva, *A Fúria*, (2010):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Y804BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM0ojwmLnKAhXGfRoKHeBIAHMQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=%22tempo%20o%20suficiente%22&f=false)

> Queria mentir, dizer que tinha tempo ***o suficiente*** para conseguir uma ambulância e salvar a sua vida se isso ainda fosse possível,

And though rare, we can find such usage in Portugal too. I’ve even found ***a suficiente***:

> O responsável acredita que a novidade do evento não criou ***motivação a suficiente*** para que tal acontecesse. [(Notícias de Setúbal, *Missão de Fé*, 6-5-2013)](http://noticiasdesetubal.pt/node/847)

This is so close to home, I should go and check it’s not a typo.

Comment: doesn't your citation `Como modificador de adjetivos, o uso de o suficiente parece ser ainda mais recente:

O parque, grande o suficiente para conter um estádio de futebol, é ricamente arborizado e possui uma vegetação rasteira que chega à altura da canela. (Luiz Alfredo Garcia Rosa, O silêncio da Chuva, 1996.)` and the substantive form after it seem like the right form to you? I think you should trim out the earlier stuff.. the first two citations clearly seem wrong, as do those leading up to the above. I deeply appreciate your answer, and will find a way to award you rep for it. Obrigado!

Comment: @robertotomás You mean *ceder-lhe o suficiente* and *ganhar o suficiente* sound wrong to you? They're perfectly standard, and far more commom than *grande o suficiente*. I answered in Portuguese. Is that alright to you? Most of the answer are quotes anyway.

Comment: Os teus exemplos não são homogéneos. O primeiro caso, em que "o suficiente" se segue a um verbo, parece-me um caso de simples elisão, como em «Dinheiro? Não temos o [dinheiro] suficiente para isso.» Um caso mais interessante é quando aparece associado a um adjetivo: «não é grande o suficiente». Aparecem-me exatamente zero casos no séc XIX no corpus portugues para ajetivo + o suficiente e adjetivo + o bastante, parece ser um fenómeno recente e (pessoalmente) soa-me informal. Os casos em que se segue a um nome parecem relativamente estranhos e não sei bem como os interpretar, mas (continua)

Comment: @Artefacto queres dizer sec. XIX? Precisamente. Eu incluí na resposta os exemplos mais antigos de cada tipo.

Comment: no primeiro caso parece-me apenas uma liberdade poética (iguala a estrutura à da primeira frase). O segundo, sem mais, parece-me simplesmente um desvio por analogia a outras ocorrências de "o suficiente". O CETEMPúblico tem zero ocorrências relevantes para `[pos="N.*"] "o" "suficiente"`. O último é claramente uma gralha.

Comment: Sim, queria. Desculpa tive de apagar os comentários anteriores porque tinha passado demasidado tempo. Espero que esteja mais claro agora. Deixei de fora o caso em que _o suficiente_ aparece a seguir a um verbo, mas como adjunto adverbial em vez de argumento.

Comment: No poema podemos alegar liberdade poética (é *o suficiente* do princípio ao fim), mas há muitos livros com *substantivo + o suficiente*

Comment: É possível que *o suficiente* objeto direto tenha começado por elisão. Mas gramaticalizou-se, ao ponto de ganhar definição nos dicionários. Também há *o importante* (mais como sujeito) *o (mais) aconselhável, o absurdo* etc.

Comment: Não teria **_o_** talvez ainda a função de artigo definido, de modo que **_tempo o suficiente_** equivalha a **_o tempo suficiente_**? A construção soa-me também um pouco como um tipo de "topicalização reduzida" (digo por analogia às "orações reduzidas"), como se quisesse-se dizer **_Dinheiro, tenho o suficiente para comprar um carro._**, que passa a **_Tenho dinheiro, o suficiente para comprar um carro._** e enfim a **_Tenho dinheiro o suficiente para comprar um carro._**.

Comment: São apenas especulações baseadas na minha impressão ao ouvir e falar. Acho que a explicação dada na resposta é bem melhor, mas um estudo linguístico do fenômeno seria mais completo ao descartar essas hipóteses de algum modo. Há temas para muitos estudos acadêmicos neste fórum.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Olha que também me passou isso pela cabeça. Mas parece-me que se fosse assim, seria *a fé suficiente* > *fé a suficiente*, e *vontade a suficente*, etc. E até se encontram coisas dessas (até incluí uma na resposta), mas são raras. Já o Artefacto, vê acima, sugeriu uma coisa semelhante para o *o suficiente* original (ter o suficiente para, etc.).

Comment: @Jacinto Tens razão. Acredito que aqui Brasil falar-se-ia antes _fé **o** suficiente_ e _vontade **o** suficiente_, sem que o artigo concorde com o gênero do substantivo.